# How to create third level menu (Shopify)

Tags: shopify

Can you please guide me, How to create third level menu in shopify.

Sub Dropdown Menu for (Almost) Any Shopify theme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... show your attempt?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In navigation:
If your Shopify backend updated then simple drag and drag upto three level
see: screenshot http://prntscr.com/hzu8n3
Or use as create new menu with same handle of sub menu.

**And use below code**

```
<div class="menuItems">
    <ul class="mebItemParent">
      {% for link in linklists.mobile-menu.links %}
      {% if linklists[link.handle] == empty %}
      <li class=""><a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="hasSubItem">
        <div class="withtiggle">
          <a href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a> <span class="toggleItem">+</span>
        </div>
        <ul>
          {% for l in linklists[link.handle].links %}
          {% if linklists[l.handle] == empty %}
          <li class=""><a href="{{ l.url }}">{{ l.title }}</a></li>
          {% else %}
          <li class="hasSubItem">
            <div class="withtiggle">
              <a href="{{ l.url }}">{{ l.title }}</a> <span class="toggleItem">+</span>
            </div>
            <ul>
              {% for l2 in linklists[link.handle].links %}
              <li class=""><a href="{{ l2.url }}">{{ l2.title }}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          </li>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
```